# Add placement options for all floats (figures and tables) at once?

Tags: floats, positioning, figure-placement

Say I want the `!htbp` placement option for every single float in my document. Other than adding it manually as in

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
...
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
...
\end{table}
```

is there a way to add this option for all floats automatically in one command, so I don't have to type it out every time?

Comment: You could redefine `\fps@figure` and `\fps@table`. But instead of using `!`, I would recommend to [adapt the other floating parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017).

Comment: The float package provides `\floatplacement` (page 3).